# How to Refresh table with kendo datasource updates from object, not from ajax request

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have an issue, when I bind data with kendo to a Table I'm using a kendo.data.DataSource object and I'm binding to a table like:

```
    <table class="myClass" id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-bind="visible:Name">Name.Title"</th>
                <th data-bind="visible:Type">Type.Title"</th>
                <th data-bind="visible: DateAdded">"CreatedDate.Title"</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="contactsListView" data-role="listview"
               data-bind="source: ListViewSource"
               data-template="Template"></tbody>
    </table>
```

on JS I am filling like this:

```
ListViewSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
    serverPaging: true, // <-- Do paging server-side.
    serverSorting: true, // <-- Do sorting server-side.
    transport: {
        read: {
            data: function () {
                  return globalVariableWithObjectList;
            }
        }
    },
    schema: {
        data: function () {
            return globalVariableWithObjectList;
        }
    }
}),
```

and it works for fill table on the first load, but if with some actions I add or delete an element It does not refresh on the table. I'm trying to refresh with:

ListViewSource.read();

It works when I have the kendo.data.DataSource like this:

```
contactsListViewSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
    serverPaging: true, // <-- Do paging server-side.
    serverSorting: true, // <-- Do sorting server-side.
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: myUrl,//Where I'm getting the data
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST"
        }
    },
    pageSize: 5,
    sort: { field: "CreatedDate", dir: "desc" },
    schema: {
        data: function () {
            return globalVariableWithObjectList;
        }
    }
}),
```

I am trying to reduce ajax numerous calls with only one when multiple data to update is needed, and storing data in global variables so that I can use them later. But the read() function for kendo.data.DataSource only refresh table data when it calls for an ajax request and non when I try to get data from the global variable, does anyone knows how can I make it work while reading from the variable ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `contactsListViewSource.add(newRecord);` for adding new records to the data source, it will automatically bind to HTML list (MVVM) and display it.

Call `contactsListViewSource.sync()` to send data to server. `contactsListViewSource.sync()` will call `transport.create` method if new records are added.

Working example: [ListView MVVM](https://dojo.telerik.com/AGOqiYUn)